# bash loop with curl evidencing non-linear scaling of response times

Tags: performance, bash, curl, performance-testing

I wrote this simple Bash script to detect incidence of error-pages:

```
date; 
iterations=10000; 
count_error=0; 
count_expected=0; 
for ((counter = 0; counter < iterations; ++counter)); do 
  if curl -s http://www.example.com/example/path | grep -iq error; 
  then 
    ((count_error++)); 
  else 
    ((count_expected++)); 
  fi; 
sleep 0.1; 
done; 
date;
echo count_error=$count_error count_expected=$count_expected
```

I'm finding total execution-time does not scale linearly with iteration count. 10 iterations 00:00:12, 100 in 00:01:46, 1000 in 00:17:24, 10000 in ~50 mins, 100000 in ~10 hrs

Can anyone provide insights into the non-linearity and/or improvements to the script?  Is curl unable to fire requests at rate of 10/sec?  Is GC having to periodically clear internal buffers filling up with response text ?

Comment: Is the remote server throttling your DOS attack?

Comment: internal qa environment - no remote server

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few thoughts:

- You are not creating 10 requests per second here (as you stated in the question), instead you are running the requests sequentially, i.e. as many per second as possible.
- The `;` at the end of each line is not required in Bash.
- When testing your script from my machine against a different URL, 10 iterations take 3 seconds, 100 take 31 seconds, and 1000 take 323 seconds, so the execution time scales linearly in this range.
- You could try using `htop` or `top` to identify performance bottlenecks on your client or server.
- The apache benchmark tool `ab` is a standard tool to benchmark web servers and available on most distributions. See manpage `ab(1)` for more information.

Comment: doesn't `sleep 0.1` inside my `for` loop pause 0.1 second between each curl request ?

Comment: Yes, but because curl does not return until the request is finished, it can only trigger 10 requests per second that way if the total execution time for each request is near zero. But you probably meant if it's possible to make 10 requests per second with curl if the server is arbitrarily fast. I'd suggest: yes. Again, on my machine (Core i7, 2,67 MHz), running 170 requests against a local Python `SimpleHTTPServer` took 950 ms, so curl is probably not the bottleneck unless you have a rather old machine.

Comment: actually i'm trying to limit requests to max 10 per sec -- that's why i was confused when you said i'm not creating 10 requests/sec. sure, there's some latency, but this is purely internal testing inside our data-center ( 100gps enet ). the reason i need to limit is that i'm testing against a qa server used by others for testing (including pipeline automated tests). plus, the target cluster will throttle requests, so there's no point for client to issue requests as fast as possible. goal here is to find incidence of error-pages - not load test.

Comment: Ah, ok :) You'll definitely achieve your goal of limiting with the 0.1 s pause, sorry for the confusion. Be sure to have a look at the `ab` tool I mentioned above. It can be used to fire a number of requests concurrently or sequentially. However this will work for you only if your server returns an HTTP error code for your error pages.